# flutter: why the hintText doesn't appear unless I click the textField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I set the property `hintText` of `textField`, which is placed in a `Container`, but the content of the `hintText` doesn't appear(as the first picture shows). When I click the `textField`, the `hintText` appears(as the second picture shows). So what's the problem?

[image]
[image]

```
Container(
                      width: 330,
                      height: 40,
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: inputController,
                        focusNode: focusNode,
                        style: MyTextStyle.level4,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          hintText: 'hint text here',
                          hintStyle: MyTextStyle.grey,
                          prefixIcon: MyIcon.SearchGreyIcon,
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          suffixIcon: focusNode.hasFocus ? IconButton(
                            icon: MyIcon.CloseIcon,
                            onPressed: () {
                              inputController.clear();
                            }
                          ) : Container(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: MyColor.MidGray,
                        borderRadius: MyStyle.CIRCULAR_BORDER_RADIUS,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: hint is shown only when the user actually tries to enter something, its just a design approach, you can use the label as hint too

Answer (score 0):

**You seem missing labelText ,**

**hintText** -Text that suggests what sort of input the field accepts.

**labelText** - Text that describes the input field.

```
TextField(
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Password',
      ),
    )
```